# Intent de navegação de mapa para todos os apps [montar rota]

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, android-intent, map

Estou procurando uma forma de dar opção do usuário selecionar qual app montar a sua rota (waze, google maps, uber...), mas só não funciona no google maps.

Quando o escolho, apenas mostra o local no mapa, mas não abre a navegação, como nos outros.

[Selecionando google maps para abrir a rota](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwT4l.png)

Atualmente eu estou fazendo assim:

```
val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:${mClient.lat},${mClient.lng}")
val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)

startActivity(mapIntent)
```

Eu sei que existe a opção de fazer:

```
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=${mClient.lat},${mClient.lng}")
```

Realmente abre a navegação do google maps bonitinho, mas assim para de funcionar em todos os outros apps.

Gostaria de uma forma que funcione para todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou deixar aqui como eu consegui pra ajudar quem se deparar com o mesmo problema

```
Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=${mClient.lat},${mClient.lng}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar essa extension:

```
fun Activity.openMaps(latitude: String, longitude: String) =
    try {
        val uri = "geo:$latitude,$longitude"
        startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(uri)))
    } catch (e2: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Não é possivel abrir a rota.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Comment: Se você reparar bem, é assim que eu disse que estava usando. Já achei uma solução, comentei logo a baixo